# Does ITU govern both spectrum, and applied power?

Tags: spectrum

I'm really not sure whether EE Stackexchange is the right place to ask. At the same time I'm sure it is the right place to expect a coherent reply.

I am aware of the various bands (C, S, K, X...) that are governed/allocated by the ITU globally, and allocated for utilization. From what I read online at no place is the amount of power to use on a particular band mentioned by the ITU.

I get the impression that ITU merely assigns spectrum; the amount of power to use on any particular band is a state subject. Is this correct?

Comment: I don’t think the ITU actually assign anything, this is for national or supranational authorities to do. ITU tries to get the various countries on the same page as much as possible on a number of bands, but there are significant differences from one country or region to another, in terms of allocations, power, modulation techniques, duty cycles, dwell times, and more. Even for the few bands that are actually vaguely the same all over (e.g. the 2.4 GHz ISM band), the exact boundaries, allowed power, etc. are significantly different from one region to another.

Comment: The actual allocations and limits are in the remit of the FCC in the US, national authorities in the EU (which an attempt at normalisation by ETSI, but this doesn’t always work), etc.

Comment: Ergo, authorized power is a state subject.?